# Which one is for video chat?

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

I'm a bit confused about these 2. Every time I do a search about video chat, I see people talking about FMS, but I was under the impression you can only do 2-way video chat with FMIS. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's true. Since 3.5, FMS was separated in two parts, FMSS and FMIS.
FMSS doesn't support Server Side ActionScript, it only can be used to stream videos, or broadcast livestreams using FMLE.

R,

Tamas Gronas

Comment: Only 2 way as-in? You can't have 3 or more people do a video chat, by avoiding Server Scripting and creating many Streams in the client code? As in, each client publishing to one stream and listening to other 2 streams? By this way we won't even need FMIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make some simple video chat application I'd go with Red5 since it is open source.

http://www.red5.org/

Comment: Yeah, I love Red5 and prefer it. But the client wants FMS

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the impression you can only do 2-way video chat with FMIS. Is this true?

Actually it is not true. You can do many 2 many video chat software with FMIS.

Instead of FMIS you can also use Red5 (free, open source, java) or Wowza.